# Check if Google Places is already verified

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-places-api, google-places

It's possible to check, using google place api, if a place was already verified/confirmed by it's owner? I wish to know if the owner has already "claimed" his place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, there don't appear to be any `isVerified` or `isVerifiedByOwner` flags on the Place Detail response: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details

So, I think the answer is "no."

Comment: Sadly .... You are right. Found this request on code.google .... https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3894